# Add ID or Class to Markdown-element

Tags: markdown, multimarkdown

Is it possible to add an id or class to a (multi)markdown element?

For example a table, a paragraph or  block of code?

I would like to style a table with css but non of following work:

```
[captionid][This is the caption, not the table id]
| First Header  | Second Header |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
```

---

```
| First Header  | Second Header |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
[captionid][This is the caption, not the table id]
```

---

```
| First Header  | Second Header |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
[tablecaption](#tableid)
```

---

```
<div class="special_table">

| First Header  | Second Header |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |

</div>
```

Can't find anything else online..

I dont mean github or stackoverflow flavored markdown btw.

Answer (score 15):

For CSS purposes you could add an id to the previous element and then use a selector to alter the following element.

Markdown like this:

```
<div class="special_table"></div>

| First Header  | Second Header |
| ------------- | ------------- |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
| Content Cell  | Content Cell  |
```

CSS like this:

```
div.special_table + table tr:nth-child(even) {background: #922}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can add a custom class or id to an element by putting the class or id inside a curly bracket after the element like this: `{#id .class}`

For example:

```
[Read more](http://www.stackoverflow.com "read more"){#link-sf .btn-read-more}
```

will be rendered like below:

`<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" title="read more" id="link-sf" class="btn-read-more">Read more</a>`

You can refer to https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#spe-attr

Comment: Personally, this one doesn't work on docusaurus :(

Comment: how will this work for tables?

Comment: not working on mkdocs either

Answer (score 6):

After some research, I come up with a simple and straight forward solution :)

I placed tables in between of two HTML placeholders and used jQuery to fine tune those and only those as needed:

### Beginning of Table

```
<div class="tables-start"></div>
```

### Table

`id | name
---|---
1  | London
2  | Paris
3  | Berlin`

### End of Table

```
<div class="tables-end"></div>
```

### jQuery: Fine tune tables by adding the classes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    $('div.tables-begin').nextUntil('div.tables-end', 'table').addClass('table table-bordered');
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Just wrap the markdown table with a div :) ? and then .foo table { color: red; } - why javascript?

Comment: Good point @BadrHari, however question clearly asks how to add "Class" or "Id" to markdown element ;)

Comment: It should be  $('div.tables-start'), not  $('div.tables-begin')

Comment: @BadrHari - Tried that under mkdocs-material and as a side effect the enclosed markdown was not translated to html.

Answer (score 0):

I was using [just the docs](https://pmarsceill.github.io/just-the-docs) and the solution was a little different. DAMIEN JIANG point me in the right direction. This did the trick for me:

`[[2]](references#2){: #references-2 }`

Which is rendered like:

`<a href="references#2" id="references-2">[2]</a>`

Comment: This one also doesn't work on docusaurus