# How to add some classes in HTML file after rendering with Jekyll

Tags: ruby, regex, markdown, jekyll

I use Jekyll and I need to add classes in a HTML tags after rendering Markdown to HTML.

I could use jQuery or simple JavaScript for this task but I would like to understand how hooks work with Jekyll.

I wrote this in a Gemfile:

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :pages, :post_render do |post|
    # here I need write something with Ruby language
end
```

Only a few pages from a collection are affected by this: How can I do it?

I would like to add this:

```
class="line-numbers"
```

For all `pre` tags in the HTML rendered file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to parse one collection's documents, you can do it with [Nokogiri](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/).

You can use a `_plugins/hook_pre.rb` like this :

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :documents, :post_render do |document|
    require 'nokogiri'
    # as posts are also a collection, we can have a document from posts
    # or even from another collection
    #### SET YOUR COLLECTION NAME HERE ####
    isSearchable = document.collection.label == 'mycollection'

    if isSearchable == true
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(document.output)
        pre = doc.css("pre").add_class('line-numbers')
        document.output = doc.to_html
    end
end
```

Comment: It's work very well, thank you. More one thing, if I want a variable in a front matter (yaml) with options like -> pre-render: ['line-number', 'other-stuff'] and use this for add a class in pre tag in a HTML file. Can you help please ?

Comment: `pre-render` front matter variable can be accessed with  `document.data['pre-render']` in your plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer: [Add ID or Class to Markdown-element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732028/add-id-or-class-to-markdown-element/14732363#14732363)

You add a class like this:

```
{:.line-numbers}
{% highlight ruby %}
def print_hi(name)
  puts "Hi, #{name}"
end
```

Which would add class `line-numbers` to the `<figure>` tag, which wraps `<pre>`, hope that helps.

Comment: This is it. I start from a Markdown document, so I can not use the Liquid language (technically yes, but not on this case).

I would like use the Ruby language instead. Thanks.